# Triggering click event using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, triggers, click, dom-events

I want to trigger a click event using javaScript. I've done it using jQuery like this:

```
$('button[type="submit"]').trigger('click'):
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
document.getElementById('buttonID').click();
```

in vanilla JS

Answer (score 1):

```js
function callClick() {
  document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click();
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" onmouseover="callClick();" onclick="alert('Click called!')">Submit</button>
```

This should do the trick:

```
document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]').click();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) . The `HTMLElement.click()` method simulates a mouse click on an element.When `click()` is used with supported elements (such as an `<input>`), it fires the element's click event. This event then bubbles up to elements higher in the document tree (or event chain) and fires their click events.

Syntax

```js
setTimeout(function(){
  let submit =document.getElementById('submit');
  submit.click();
},2000)

function submited(){
  alert('submitted');
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submited()">
 <input type="text">
 <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```